# Исключить строки после группировки с минимальным значением поля

Tags: sql, big-data

> Нужно исключить email у которых min(date_reg) <2016-02-01. использование min обязательно

запрос  в google bigquery

```
select users.email, sum(s.price) as sum_price
from test.users as users
join (select * from test.sales) as s on users.user_id=s.user_id
join (select * from test.lesson) as l on users.email=l.email
group by users.email
```

Структура таблиц:

**test.users**

- user_id
- date_reg
- email

**test.lesson**

- email

**test.sales**

- price
- user_id

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что домашнюю работу надо делать самостоятельно.

Comment: с удовольствием бы так и поступил, если бы знал как - на данный момент я в тупике.вопрос задан не для того чтобы выдать чужое решение за свое, а для того чтобы понять структуру запроса.

Comment: @Akina перечитайте, пожалуйста https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/ и http://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4882/. То, что вопрос - это чье-то учебное задание - не может служить причиной закрытия сам по себе.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно подобные условия по агрегатным функциям легко реализуются через `having`.
Если кроме условия про `min(reg_date)` в целом ваш запрос работает корректно, просто добавьте `having`.

Также необходимо привести поле `date_reg` к типу даты для корректного сравнения: `DATE(u.reg_date)` либо наоборот, привести строку к таймстемпу:  `u.reg_date = TIMESTAMP('2016-02-01')` - это зависит от того, какого типа у вас поле `reg_date`

```
select users.email, sum(s.price) as sum_price
from test.users as users
join (select * from test.sales) as s on users.user_id=s.user_id
join (select * from test.lesson) as l on users.email=l.email
group by users.email
having min(DATE(users.reg_date)) >= '2016-02-01'
```

Join подзапросов у вас очень странный, так никто не делает. Я бы написал так:

```
select u.email, sum(s.price) as sum_price
from users as u
join sales as s on u.user_id=s.user_id
join lesson as l on u.email=l.email
group by u.email
having min(DATE(u.reg_date)) >= '2016-02-01'
```

Comment: Еще join упростите. А то так и привыкнет человек усложнять себе жизнь лишними select :)

Comment: @vp_arth join исправил, но при добавлении `having` возникает ошибка
_Argument type mismatch in function GREATER: 'f0_' is type int64, '2016-02-01 00:00:00' is type string_

Comment: @mixail, обновил ответ

Comment: @vp_arth сам код работает, но выводит пустое значение. видимо я не правильно сформировал вопрос и чего-то не хватает. нужно чтобы отфильтровались email у которых `min(DATE(u.reg_date)) <'2016-02-01'`

Comment: а если `date(min(u.reg_date))`?

Comment: @vp_arth тоже пусто.

Comment: Добавьте `min(date(u.reg_date))` в `select` уберите `having` и посмотрите значения, есть ли там подходящие. возможно в данных просто нет настолько ранних регистраций

Comment: @vp_arth нужные данные есть. если использовать выражение `where u.email not in (select email from users where reg_date < '2016-02-01 00:00:00')` то выводится нужный результат, но вопрос в том как это сделать с использованием агрегирующей `min()`

Comment: Меня смущает условие `not in` в этом вашем выражении. Скорее всего вы таким образом выбираете все `reg_date >= '2016-02-01'` - Ну конечно) В вопросе же написано - **исключить**